# How to calculate line break in textarea - JavaScript | React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Context**

In my React app I have a form with a text area field where users can type their text input.

**Required behaviour**

If it is 1 line of text then it should be vertically centered via `padding-top: 25px`

If it is 2 lines of text then it should be vertically centered via `padding-top: 15px`.

**My current solution**

The `height` of the textarea input is fixed. I check whether there is 1 or 2 lines of text and provide the `padding-top` accordingly. Also I check for the number of characters in line 1.

```
        const getNumOfLines = (str: string): number => (str.match(/\n/g) || '').length + 1;

        const initialNumOfLines = getNumOfLines(value);

        const [textAreaPadding, setTextAreaPadding] = useState({
            paddingTop: initialNumOfLines > 1 || value.length > 34 ? '15px' : '25px',
        });

        const resizeAndHandleChange = (event: FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>): void => {
            const text = event.currentTarget.value;

            const getNumOfLines = (str: string): number => (str.match(/\n/g) || '').length + 1;
            const numOfLines = getNumOfLines(text);

            setTextAreaPadding({ paddingTop: numOfLines > 1 || text.length > 34 ? '15px' : '25px' });
            onChange(event.currentTarget.value, contentId);

            console.log(text.length);
        };
```

**The problem with my solution**

My solution is working when users hit Enter and write text in a 2nd line of text.

It is not working when users just continue typing in line 1. At some point the automatic line break into 2nd line will happen.

And that one I cannot calculate. As you see in my solution I tried to calculate the text length and force a update of `padding-top` when `text.length > 34`.

`text.length` counts spaces and letters. However, depending on what the users write (length of words, number of spaces) the automatic line break is at different `text.lenght`!

So I cannot put a fixed `text.length` here and must calculate differently.

Any ideas?

Comment: i guess u can't check when the line is wrapped, but u can check scrollHeight attribute of the element, maybe

Comment: Yes, this was a good idea. I tried it and it looks promising. 
But: the `scrollheight` is changing once the user inputs a 2nd letter into the 2nd line. The 1st letter in 2nd line is without change of scrollHeight.